# UIColor always gives white when settings blue

Tags: uiimageview, background-color, uicolor

I'm trying to set the background color of a UIImageView with this (It should return some green-ish color):

```
 cell.background.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:50 green:200 blue:50 alpha:1];
```

But for some reason this is only giving me a white color, it seems that whenever I set the blue it turns back to white, when I do this, it returns me yellow, which is normal:

```
cell.background.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:50 green:200 blue:0 alpha:1];
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, I didn't realize UIColor requires a float from 0 - 1, not from 0 - 255, this works:

```
cell.background.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:240.0f/255.0f green:245.0f/255.0f blue:254.0f/255.0f alpha:1];
```